# Why Alias name is not getting track in Link Name for CloudPageURL function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-link, cloudpagesurl

We have multiple CTAs or Links in single email and we are using the CloudpageURL function to redirect the subscribers based on Expiry date condition along with Alias. But alias in not getting track into Linkname column of Click view. I can only see the URL in both URL and Linkname (e.g https://web.sfmc.com/ExpiryFn?qs=51a9ae80fe1aa752ded5b05d50b12bdfcde2089) column not alias. Kindly suggest how to track the alias to distinguish the URLs.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(0001, 'ExpirationDate',@expdate, 'Destination', @des,'Fallback',@falback))=%%" alias="Test">
```

Comment: It looks like the `alias` value in the code pasted here is not completely wrapped; a double-quote (`"`) is missing at the end. See if adding the missing quote works (`alias="Test"`).

Comment: @MarkG- Sorry it was a type mistake so I have edited the code. Thank you to highlight it and kindly suggest if  there any such way to track the alias.

Comment: @AVashisth Are your CTA's inside of impression regions?

Comment: @jake314159- No, CTA's simply inside the HTML and not used Impression region. We can see alias for some of the clicks but not for all.